# Comparing numpy array of datetimes with timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am not understanding why this code throws an error. Isn't '>' vectorized? I can see there is no problem with `x_month_begin[0,0] > st_d` comparison. Would appreciate insights and fix suggestions.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime




    end_d = pd.to_datetime('23/02/2018', format="%d/%m/%Y")


    x_month_begin = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(year=end_d.year-1, month=1, day=1), 
                                      datetime.datetime(year=end_d.year+1, month=12, day=1), freq='MS')

    # stacking with each row for each year        
    x_month_begin = np.vstack(np.split(x_month_begin, 3))
    # transposing for each column to be a year
    x_month_begin = np.transpose(x_month_begin)

    st_d = pd.to_datetime('01/2016', format="%m/%Y")

    x_month_begin > st_d
```

Comment: Can you share `end_d` object?

Comment: _why this code throws an error._ What error?

Comment: Added the end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you start off with a pandas structure:

```
In [133]: x_month_begin                                                         
Out[133]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
               '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

the same thing as a numpy array:

```
In [134]: x_month_begin.values                                                  
Out[134]: 
array(['2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-05-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-07-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

You manipulate that into a (n,3) array (I suspect this can be done more directly with a reshape and possible transpose):

```
In [135]: x_month_begin = np.vstack(np.split(x_month_begin, 3))                 
In [138]: x_month_begin = np.transpose(x_month_begin)                           
In [139]: x_month_begin                                                         
Out[139]: 
array([['2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
        '2020-09-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
        '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-07-01T00:00:00.000000000',
        '2020-11-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2020-04-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
        '2020-12-01T00:00:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
In [140]: _.shape                                                               
Out[140]: (4, 3)
```

Any ways, now your comparison:

```
In [141]: st_d = pd.to_datetime('01/2016', format="%m/%Y")                      
In [142]: st_d                                                                  
Out[142]: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00')
In [143]: x_month_begin >st_d                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-30567662e59d> in <module>
----> 1 x_month_begin >st_d

pandas/_libs/tslibs/c_timestamp.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp._Timestamp.__richcmp__()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

`numpy` arrays can do `<` comparisons, but they have certain rules about what `dtypes` are compatible.  (e.g. comparing strings and numbers doesn't work).  In addition `pandas` plays its own games with dates and times, some formats are internal, some are compatible with the numpy `datatime64`.

For example if we convert your timestamp to a numpy equivalent:

```
In [144]: st_d.to_numpy()                                                       
Out[144]: numpy.datetime64('2016-01-01T00:00:00.000000000')
```

the comparison works:

```
In [145]: x_month_begin>st_d.to_numpy()                                         
Out[145]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

`pandas` is built on `numpy`, or at least uses `numpy` arrays to store its data.  But none of the `numpy` code is `pandas` aware.  If given a non-numpy object it will try, naively, to convert it, e.g.

```
In [146]: np.asarray(st_d)                                                      
Out[146]: array(Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), dtype=object)
```

is different from `Out[144]`. [146] is the conversion that produces your error.

```
The original `DatetimeIndex` can be tested against the timestamp.  That's a 'pure' pandas operation.

In [152]: _133>st_d                                                             
Out[152]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True])
```

`_133.to_numpy().reshape(-1,4).T` gives the `x_month_begin` array directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the type of objects, the problem becomes clear.

1. `x_month_begin`: is a 3 dimensional numpy array (`x_month_begin.shape`)
2. `st_d`: is a pandas timestamp variable

Both cannot be compared directly. For comparison, you can do something like this:

`[y > st_d for x in x_month_begin for y in x ]`